# Add a file to a git repository but ignore future changes on it

Tags: git

I want to add an `overrides.json`.  That allows developers to make changes to a config object locally.  I want it added to the repository in a default state but I want future changes on it to be ignored.

It seems like `.gitignore` forces me to remove it from the branch before I can ignore it.  I know about `git update-index` but each developer would have to do this manually.  To clarify, I do not want the file removed; I actually want the file to be added to repository but untracked after that.

I can't simply remove it because `GET` requests to a missing file throws ugly error messages in the browser's javascript console.

Comment: couldn't you make the file read only and then commit it ?

Comment: No, I want developers to change it locally.  This would be for enabling dev type features but keeping them out of the production config.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git ignore local changes to tracked files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756531/git-ignore-local-changes-to-tracked-files)

Comment: see this answer for similar solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348590/how-can-i-make-git-ignore-future-revisions-to-a-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make git ignore future revisions to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348590/how-can-i-make-git-ignore-future-revisions-to-a-file)

Answer (score 41):

After adding the file you can ignore all further changes by doing:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file
```

If at some point you decide that you need to push more changes you can allow again changes by doing:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file
```

Instead of adding the files in the repo, why not ignore them and add them to a different location, eg. a setup directory. This way after cloning the repo, the developers will need to execute an init step that will copy the needed files in the proper location, where they are ignored.

Comment: As I stated earlier, this requires the developers to do this manually.  I can't "`push`" this `--assumed-unchanged` to the repository.  I'm worried that developers will just do `git add .` and their changes will get pushed into the repository.

Comment: @BrennanCheung No, unfortunately I don't know a good way to propagate the `assume-unchanged` flag. But see my updated answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Ignore it and don't add it to the repo. Instead, generate a default version by the project's makefile if it does not exist. Assuming of course that you have a makefile, or any kind of make or build process.

Comment: This sounds like it would work but it's not ideal.  If I was going to do that I might as well use the Rails style (development|test|production) sections in the config file.  However, this is an AngularJS app and has no server component other than nginx so I would have to make a custom build process and do it at that time.  It's a possible solution but way overboard if I can find a solution within git.

Comment: Is AngularJS able to create the file on the client side?