# Eclipse M2E changing org.eclipse.wst.common.component

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have a multi-module Maven Java (WAR) project in Eclipse.  It depends on a bunch of other Java projects.  We check our .settings directory into source control because there are many manually established settings in there.

One of the files in .settings is `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` which also has manually established settings.  However, Eclipse is constantly modifying that file based on which underlying JAR projects the developer has open in Eclipse.  I believe it does this to help accomplished "workspace resolution" of those artifacts.

However, the result of this situation is that Eclipse is constantly modifying that `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` and developers are constantly committing it to source control and fighting over it with one another.   Leaving those files out of source control does not work as there are too many manual tweaks in there that are specific to each project.

I am guessing that it is a design flaw in Eclipse to have a file that combines project settings and users settings together!  If anyone has any insight into how to better handle this problem that would be great.  As it is, Eclipse-M2E is simply not working for team development on complex projects unless every developer has EXACTLY the same Java projects loaded....

Comment: I've just discovered this problem in my own workspace. What did you end up doing to resolve? Have you used IntelliJ with this Maven project before? If so, how is it?

Comment: I know this is going to sound ridiculous, or like an exaggeration, or like a paid advertisement.  But this was the issue that broke the camel's back... after this I was finally forced to let the team tryout Intellij.  I'm not saying it's without flaws, but it is so much better than Eclipse, I really regret having not switched years ago.  A huge blunder on my part.

Comment: For the most part, IntelliJ has a fairly clean separation between workspace files and project files so that things like this do not happen.  Again, it's not perfect but it's ten times better.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that that particular file is problematic... If it gets corrupted, the workspace will probably crash, and if it's missing - nothing will work. 
But it contains nothing that can't be generated from scratch when re-importing a project...

I think the best solution is to check in the file using the "full" workspace, and then make sure that future changes are ignored.

If you then need to do a "real" change, load the full workspace, do whatever you need to do, and then un-ignore the file, check in, and then ignore it again.

- Eclipse Git: Team->Advanced->Assume unchanged.
- Git: [Add a file to a git repository but ignore future changes on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854559/add-a-file-to-a-git-repository-but-ignore-future-changes-on-it)

ex:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged the-file
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged the-file
```

- Mercurial: Use a file template: [Mercurial: How to ignore changes to a tracked file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856571/mercurial-how-to-ignore-changes-to-a-tracked-file)
- Eclipse RTC: ignore

With some luck, m2e will mess around with the jar/project references so it matches the loaded projects. If it doesn't do it automatically, update the project definition.