# I want to commit a file to repository but the content of the files should be ignored

Tags: git, github-actions, gitignore

I would like to ignore the contents of the file to be uncommitted every time I make a new commit to GitHub and i want the file entry in repository

C:\Test\src\app\configs\change.json

How can we ignore the contents of the file to be unchanged?

Used .gitignore to ignore a file to be committed which is not helpful.
Read about

```
--skip-worktree
```

[How can I make git ignore future revisions to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348590/how-can-i-make-git-ignore-future-revisions-to-a-file)

Would like to understand where and how this should be tested locally and on CI

Comment: The way to tell git to ignore changes to a file that is tracked is using `git update-index --assume-unchanged the-file`.

Comment: @eftshift0 where do i run this commands? is it in the project directory of the IDE terminal?

Comment: In the terminal, inside the directory of the project.

Comment: Thanks @eftshift0 how about the CI? what if different developer can commit a change to this file? Is there a way i can tell the pipeline(in azure.yml) to ignore the contents of the file?

Comment: Why is `change.json` in the repository if you don't want to track changes the content?

Comment: I guess you should play a little bit with hooks so that if someone wants to _push_ a change into that file, it gets rejected

Comment: @chepner because that file is referenced in different files and build is failing

Comment: @eftshift0 is there any documentation to refer how to reject a file? i would really want to make this change as we don't have any alternative

Comment: That's a bug to fix, not a bug for Git to *prevent*.