# .gitignore for config file

Tags: git, config, gitignore

Let's say we have three files in a GIT repo:

```
.gitignore   (file content:  config.py)
config.py
main.py
```

When we clone this repo with `git clone https://github.com/example/test`, we now have these 3 files in a folder, which is ok.

Now let's do local modifications to `config.py`.

Then a few days later, we want to pull the latest modifications with `git pull`. Problem: it also wants to merge `config.py`:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
> config.py

which we don't want.

TL;DR, this is the desired workflow:

- during the first `git clone ...`, `config.py` should be cloned
- during the next `git pull ...`, `config.py` shouldn't be pulled/merged/overwritten if it has been locally modified

**What's the standard way to handle this situation?**

Comment: The most common ways of handling this is creating a file ```config.py.example``` with some dummy values. The user then have to copy ```config.py.example``` to ```config.py``` after clone and adjust it.

Comment: @flappix Yes that's what I did up to now, but I was curious if an even simpler workflow would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is to put `config.py.template` (or whatever you want to call it) in the repo, with the formatting and default values for `config.py`. People who want to use the repo will need to clone the repo, copy that file to `config.py`, and make their local changes.

A slightly different option is to use CI/CD to reject any commit that modifies `config.py`. This is not as useful, though, because you won't be able to update `config.py` to include new options or remove old ones.

Note that `.gitignore` is not retroactive - if you've already added `config.py` then you'll need to run `git rm --cached config.py` to remove it from the index.

Comment: Thanks! So I'll keep my standard worfklow (shipping `example_config.py` that the user has to copy) Can't `.gitignore` be used to tell "Don't download/merge `config.py`" during future `git pull` calls?

Comment: No, because `.gitignore` is only meant for ignoring files when they're added to the staging area. It isn't currently checked during pulls or fetches.

Comment: @Basj Not `.gitignore`. It never affects files that are already tracked. What you're describing is along the lines of `git update-index --skip-worktree config.py`. See [How can I make git ignore future revisions to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4348590/11082165)

Comment: [The Git FAQ is very clear](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) that ignoring tracked files is not possible, not even with `git update-index`.  The accepted answer to that question is wrong and contradicts the documentation.