# How to discard changes in a specific file before pushing

Tags: java, git, version-control

Is there a way to reset all changes or a mechanism like .gitignore where changes to a certain file will be not pushed.
Let's say I have a prod-settings.property

```
 link=acbdc.com/acnbdsds
 password=enter password
 name=enter name
```

In order to run it locally, I need to enter those password and name. But I'd like to be sure that those to be ignored when I push my changes and create a PR to prevent an accident. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.gitignore for config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77290276/gitignore-for-config-file)

Comment: @JimRedmond thanks! but no, I'd like to keep this file like a template and prevent any changes being pushed

Comment: If `prod-settings.property` is ignored from the outset, and only `prod-settings.property.template` (name TBD) is part of the repo, then updates to the `prod-settings.property.template` version won't affect `prod-settings.property` without manual intervention. Otherwise, you'll have to rely on CI/CD to enforce this.

Comment: Try [smudge and clean filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155355/6330106) if you want a Git solution.