# git reverse cherrypick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

My question is, is there a way to mark a specific commit(s) so that either it won't be merged into another branch, or it will be ignored when I issue a "git push" or fetch from another repository?

My understanding is that you can cherry-pick specific commits to merge into the current branch; is there some way to mark a commit as 'local' to a specific machine/repository/branch?

---

The problem this question grew out of, I am currently solving a different way. Specifically, there is a specific version of sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5) that I require to work on a Rails application on one OSX machine to which I don't have root access. Right now I've made the commit to specify the version in the Gemfile on a local branch called "mac-bundle", and my plan is simply to switch to that branch and merge necessary changes before I run bundle if I need to install a ruby gem.

Which is a minor but live-withable annoyance. It seems possible that a similar situation might arise where the same workaround won't be quite as acceptable, so I thought I would ask for ideas on a different solution.

(Question similar to this one: [Committing Machine Specific Configuration Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/git-committing-machine-specific-configuration-files) , and my current solution is similar to Greg Hewgill's answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not a way to mark a commit as "not to be included in merges". Using separate branches is pretty much as close as it gets.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was expecting, but I thought I'd ask on the off-chance.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You can however "fake a commit" on a particular branch.

To do that, you can

```
git merge OtherBranchName --no-commit
```

This applies the changes and leaves it in the index for you to take action. Then, you can manually remove the changes applied and commit.

Git then thinks *that* commit has been applied on this branch, and you both live happily thereafter.

However, this might be ok as a one off, specifically to deal with configuration files. But you should not make this a general practice.

Comment: That seems pretty close in effect to what I was asking for, but it definitely feels like something that could cause weird problems later. Thanks for the suggestion, though!