# ignoring local config files in git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, gitignore

There are some local files (that are part of our repository) in a rails app that I would like git to ignore. Basically, I'd like git to ignore all changes I make to anything in the config/environments directory and to the config/application.rb file. I don't want to use .gitignore because I don't want OTHER people working on the code base to have their configurations ignored by git. Basically I'm doing a lot of testing that modifies the config files and sometimes my config changes are checked into a github which at a minimum is embarassing and at worst causes issues with the production environment.

What's the best approach here?

Comment: check for the .gitignore file.If not just create a file .gitignore and mention the list of files you want to ignore like this   config/database.yml
/config/*.yml
# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Committing Machine Specific Configuration Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/committing-machine-specific-configuration-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a [global .gitignore](http://ashleyangell.com/2011/07/system-wide-git-global-ignores/).

Although, it will still see changes in files that already **are** in the repository. Here's how you [work around this](http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/). You can probably make a bash macro out of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `git update-index --assume-unchanged config/application.rb` and git will not notice any changes you make to the local copy of that file unless you explicitly use `git add`.

My understanding is that `.gitignore` and friends won't change how files that are already put into the repository are handled, only whether untracked files are presented as candidates.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [global .gitignore](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/) that would be your machine specific, not checked into project repository.

Comment: dumb question: why is this called global and not local?

Comment: @Ramy: it's global across all repositories (on this machine).

Answer (score 0):

check for the .gitignore file.If not just create a file .gitignore and mention the list of files you want to ignore like this   config/database.yml

```
 /config/*.yml
/log/*.log /tmp
```