# How to ignore existing file in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I need to work on `file.txt` locally and in Git, with different content. I want Git not to tell me that there have been changes to that file.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Committing Machine Specific Configuration Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/committing-machine-specific-configuration-files)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, you want `--skip-worktree`, not `--assume-unchanged`. [Here's a good explanation why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/467386).

So `git update-index --skip-worktree file.txt`

TLDR; `--assume-unchanged` is for performance, for files that won't change (like SDKs); `--skip-worktree` is for files that exist on remote but that you want to make local (untracked) changes to.

Comment: Please add the full command to your answer (`git update-index ...`); Some of us are true git newbies and I had to read below @janos's answer to complement yours ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you want to "pretend" that the file hasn't changed when actually it did? You can do that like this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file.txt
```

To undo this later:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file.txt
```

To view a list of files that are marked this way:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]'
```

**UPDATE**

As comments have pointed out, this is most probably NOT what you want to do.
A [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27301155/641955) has been posted by [@Tom Auger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467386/tom-auger), use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

If modifying the `.gitignore` file is not an option (because it is checked into git itself), consider using `.git/info/exclude`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use [.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) file?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

All you need is to click the `more` button in sourcetree just at the right hand side of the filename, in the unstaged files section. Click `ignore` and make source tree perform your desired action for that file or all the files with the same type.

Answer (score 1):

SOURCETREE Terminal codes

Add ignore file:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree index.php
```

Extract ignore file:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree index.php
```

List ignore files:

```
git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others
```

Comment: Good answer for me because I'm using SourceTree. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Luna, this can be done [with EGit plugin I think] by doing this:
right-click file -> Team -> Advanced -> Assume unchanged