# How do I tell git to ignore my local changes, but leave the file in my remote repo?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Constantly changing my web.config file when testing/pushing to production gets old, so does having to remember to remove that from my staged changes when I don't change the file.

I have tried using selecting the "stop tracking" option in Sourcetree (which I think adds the file to my GitIgnore), but that looks like it will remove the file from my remote repo.

Is it possible to leave a file *in* my remote repo, and stop tracking local changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using conditional configuration files with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498844/using-conditional-configuration-files-with-git)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore existing file in Git using source tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525055/how-to-ignore-existing-file-in-git-using-source-tree)

Comment: @meagar Can you go into more detail about this/do you have documentation or an article explaining a better process? Is it still possible to not use a checked in config file when using Git Deploy?

Comment: See the linked question. It's an exact duplicate, somebody trying to store environment-specific configuration in Git. I gave an answer there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Committing Machine Specific Configuration Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/committing-machine-specific-configuration-files)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>
```

If you want to undo it later, use:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filename>
```

Comment: Note that this affects the local repository only. If other developers clone the repository, their changes to these files will *not* be ignored.

Comment: where do I put this command?  I am having a similar problem.  I want git local to just ignore some of the local config files I am working on.  Either indefinitely or for today or x hours.

Comment: @JonGrah If you're using SourceTree, you hit the Terminal Button, navigate to the file and then applying the command listed by Lucas.

Comment: Brilliant answer!