# How to make Git ignore changes I'm making to a file (under source control)?

Tags: git

I am using git for big web application. At my local end I want to make few files unchanged during work flow of git. For example there is database and config files which have different content as compare to live server. I don't want to let files over written by any of git command. how I can lock or ignore config and database files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Committing Machine Specific Configuration Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/committing-machine-specific-configuration-files)

Answer (score 6):

Use the **[.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)** file for this. Such files like database configurations or folders with changing files should not be included in the git repository.

In most cases you can create a template file like

`database_config.txt_template`

and commit that file in your git repo. When a new user install that project he can rename the file and can change the settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't lock file.

Instead, you can create an example-file (so you have a base config file) and copy it at the right place.

```
git mv path/to/config path/to/config-example
echo "path/to/config" >>.gitignore
cp path/to/config-example path/to/config
```