# Git checkout changes skip-worktree files

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-skip-worktree

In my git repo, my config files (which are different on the features and master branch) have the `skip-worktree` bit on. Everything worked fine until I did a rebase on a local branch. This overwrote my local config files on my features branch.

So to I updated the config in my features branch, but when I switched branches the same changes appeared in my master too.
So basically any changes to the config files in any branch changes them in all branches when I checkout.

Did I do something wrong, and how do I ensure that changes to config files do not change on checkout?

Comment: The best course of action is to not commit configuration files at all, but keep them out-of-tree with templates only in the repository. Does <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/committing-machine-specific-configuration-files> help?