# How to ignore unmerged paths?

Tags: git, yii

Currently I'm working with yii and I use git center repository, let's say in development config is set to localhost, and in production server config is set to server ip.

I have modified file which need to commit

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   backend/modules/company/controllers/XyzController.php
```

When I commit, I get error

```
U       backend/config/main.php
U       frontend/config/main.php
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

here is `Unmerged paths`

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   backend/config/main.php
        both modified:   frontend/config/main.php
```

because it conflict with production server config when I pull from center repository.

I have already include `backend/config/main.php` and `frontend/config/main.php` in `.gitignore` but no effect.

so How can I solved it so I can commit only `XyzController.php` and push to remote?

If I commit `backend/config/main.php` and `frontend/config/main.php` then it will included in push. and it think it will conflict when in production server I pull from center repository.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't ignore files that are in the repository. Replace files with server versions, commit, then change them how you want and don't commit. If they change often on the server you have quite a manual mess at hand.

Answer (score 3):

If you have unmerged paths due to a `git stash pop` you can resolve the conflicts manually on that file and then do a `git reset filename`

Answer (score 1):

An *unmerged path* means you have run `git merge`, or the equivalent of `git merge`, and it tried to merge two different sets of changes to that file, but failed.

This means that *you* must now combine the two sets of changes in that file.  Git will have left behind, in your work-tree, its best effort at combining the two sets of changes, but Git is quite certain that what it left behind is *not correct*.  You then mention:

> let's say in development config is set to localhost, and in production server config is set to server ip ...

If the conflict is over the IP addresses in a configuration file, Git is right: it will not have resolved the conflict properly.

The danger is that by putting these files in as version-controlled files, a future `git merge` operation will think it *has* resolved a merge correctly when instead, it has put the wrong IP address in.

**Configuration files should not be version-controlled.**  See [Committing Machine Specific Configuration Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1396617/1256452) for one good way to do this.  There are others; e.g., you can commit `config.sample` rather than `config.php` and have `config.php` as an ignored file, that each user must write based on the version-controlled `config.sample`.

In the meantime, however, you still have to clean up the existing mess.  The merge conflict occurred because these two files are *already version controlled*.  Unless version-controlling them was your own mistake as part of writing the one change you just made—which seems impossible<sup>1</sup>—you should undo the version-controlling as a separate operation (independent of other changes).

Thus, you might use this procedure: Open the two conflicted files `backend/config/main.php` and `frontend/config/main.php` in your editor and check the configurations carefully.  Fix them as needed, and save the result.  Then use the commands:

```
git add backend/config/main.php
git add frontend/config/main.php
```

to put the corrected versions into place.  It's likely that they now *match* the previous versions on the current branch, so that `git status` will no longer show them at all.  (If `git status` *does* show them, use `git diff --cached` to see what you have changed.)  In any case, this will mark the two files as fully resolved in the index.  You can now make a new commit.  If the two config files match the ones in the current (`HEAD`) commit, the only thing *changed* in your new commit will be the file `backend/modules/company/controllers/XyzController.php`.

(Remember, a commit has a complete snapshot of *every* committed file.  The *next* commit you make is based on whatever is in the index right now, i.e., whatever you `git add`.  Once you make the commit, the new `HEAD` commit and the index now match, so that `git status` says that there is nothing to commit.)

---

In order to get a merge conflict, the file must be present in both tip commits, or in the merge base and one tip commit, or in all three commits.  Remember that a merge works from three versions of each file:

- the *merge base* version, which is the one that was in place before either branch began to diverge;
- the `--ours` version, which is the one in the `HEAD` commit; and
- the `--theirs` version, which is the one in the other branch tip.

If you mistakenly added a configuration file to your branch, but it was not present in the base and is not in `--theirs`, there would be no conflict.  Therefore, it must be in at least one of the other two commits.  Presumably you did not write the base version yourself, nor did you make the other branch-tip commit.  If that's true, you could not have caused this configuration-file-is-now-version-controlled issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Add` only your `XyzController.php` files, `Commit`, `Push`.

```
$ git add backend/modules/company/controllers/XyzController.php
$ git commit -m 'Added XyzController'
$ git push origin HEAD
```

It's better to Pull remote changes. If conflict occures in `backend/config/main.php`, `frontend/config/main.php` files then resolve conflicts, Add, Commit.

If you want to keep your changes of the files then, accept `ours` while pulling.

```
$ git pull origin <branch> -s recursive -X ours    # accept your changes
```